# G-Cloud SDK Application: How to authorize sdk app to access google sheets

Tags: google-app-engine, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-api-python-client

Having trouble deploying application to Google Cloud. It works fine locally but has authentication issues one Google Cloud. How do you authorize an application deployed to G-Cloud SDK to use google sheets? I've tried a variety of methods but they all fail. I think my pain point is I'm trying to authenticate as if this were a client but it isn't. I tried the service account way too but I probably messed that up. Below is the code that worked locally but can't adjust to Google SDK.

```
def get_entry():
creds = None
# The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'client_secret.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

# Call the Sheets API
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
```

Comment: Where are you running your code on GCP? On which product? And do you try to deploy this code which works locally, on GCP?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere not sure actually. I thought deploying to GCP was a singular thing. I believe I'm deploying to the App Engine, used this guide: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/quickstart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you can't run a local server on Google App Engine because of restrictions.

I recommend you use the below code:

```
if os.environ.get('GAE_ENV') == 'standard':
    creds = flow.run_console()
else:
    creds = flow.run_local_server()
```